# Why is an older version of sktime getting installed using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install `sktime` using `pip`. The latest version in [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/sktime/#description) is 0.5.1, however when I install 0.4.3 gets installed. I tried installing using pip3 install sktime==0.5.1, it throws error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sktime==0.5 (from versions: 0.1.dev0, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3)
No matching distribution found for sktime==0.5
```

Comment: Is this python 3.9?

Comment: python --version gives 3.6.9

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: No, I'm on  Ubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: Is wheel installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed outside the virtual environment

Comment: Is it installed *within* the venv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227102/discussion-between-bhaskar-dhariyal-and-superstormer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future users, relevant details from chat:

```
Ubuntu 18.0.4
pip 9.0.1
python 3.6.9
```

The issue here is that the pip version is too old to install any of the [wheel files for 0.5.1](https://pypi.org/project/sktime/0.5.1/#files). manylinux2010 support was added in pip 19.0, according to [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/issues/389). To fix this, just upgrade pip to a version >19.

So why does this issue only occur for version 0.5.1 and not any of the previous ones? It's because all of the previous version(for instance, [0.4.3](https://pypi.org/project/sktime/0.4.3/#files)) also provide a source distribution(the .tar.gz) which can be used to build from source as an alternative to wheels. However, this sdist was removed in 0.5.1.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! I've created an issue here: https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime/issues/607 to also upload the .tar.gz files to PyPI